# How to insert a picture in a document template?

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I use this tag in an odt or docx template:

```
[var.path;ope=addpic]
```

However, tinybutstrong inserts path to picture, but not picture.

Where to paste the tag that would output the picture and not its path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addpic` is an old deprecated operator in OpenTBS. It is replaced with operator `changepic` since OpenTBS version 1.4.0. Operator `addpic` is supported but for compatibility only and its usage is quite more complicated than `changepic` and no more documented.

So you should place the following just after a picture

```
[var.path;ope=changepic]
```

Or this one inside the Description or Title property of the picture :

```
[var.path;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside]
```

See [documentation](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#pic) for more details.